# Remove comments from file and keep integers

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to remove comments from my .txt file. My text file looks like this:

```
(* Sunspot data collected by Robin McQuinn from *)
(* http://sidc.oma.be/html/sunspot.html         *)

(* Month: 1749 01 *) 58
(* Month: 1749 02 *) 63
(* Month: 1749 03 *) 70
(* Month: 1749 04 *) 56
```

The comments are everything between (* and *).I need to only keep the 58,63,70, and 56 from this file.

My code is removing some of the chars but not properly. My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <numeric>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int digit = 1;
    string filename;
    //cout for getting user path
    //the compiler parses string literals differently so use a double backslash or a forward slash
    cout << "Enter the path of the data file, be sure to include extension." << endl;
    cout << "You can use either of the following:" << endl;
    cout << "A forwardslash or double backslash to separate each directory." << endl;
    getline(cin, filename);

    //gets file
    ifstream infile{filename};
    istream_iterator<char> infile_begin{ infile };
    istream_iterator<char> eof{};
    vector<char> file{ infile_begin, eof };

    for(int i =0; i < file.size(); i++){
    if(!isdigit(file[i])) {
        if(file[i] != ')') {
            file.erase(file.begin(),file.begin()+i);
        }
    }
    }
    copy(begin(file), end(file), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " "));
    }
```

Should I not use `vector.erase()`? I know that it is not right in this code. If that is the case what is the better solution? I know in C you can write it to memory and go to each location, would this be the better way?

Comment: A better solution would be to discard comments as they are read in, rather than to read in the entire file at once and then attempt to discard. Each erasure will result in the vector shifting elements. It does not sounds very efficient.

Comment: Your code is farther from working than you think. Re-think the algorithm. What does copying the stream contents to `std::vector` give you? You can do this in one iteration through the stream and a `bool` variable indicating whether you're reading inside a comment or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would first save everything as a string, prepare the string and *then* safely push_back the result into a vector.
Now I used std::regex to filter your file. It's not the easiest, though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>

int main(){

    std::string file_name;
    std::cout << "Enter name/path of the txt file: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, file_name);
    std::ifstream file(file_name);

    std::vector<int> vec; //here save integers

    std::string text; //save current line here


    std::smatch match; //here the found "comment" get's saved, later to be removed from text

    std::regex remove("[\(\*]\.*[\*\)] *"); //the expression to search for
    //translation
    //     _[\(\*]   -> (*
    //     _\.*      -> any number of characters
    //     _[\*\)]   -> *)
    //     _ *       -> any number of whitespaces (important to cast to integer)..



    while (std::getline(file, text)){ //loop through all lines in file.txt

        if (std::regex_search(text, match, remove)){ //if a comment was found
            text.erase(text.begin(), text.begin() + match[0].length()); //remove the comment
        }

        if (!text.empty()) { //empty, line was a pure comment
            vec.push_back(std::stoi(text)); //else add integer to list
        }
    }


    std::cout << "The file contains:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        std::cout << vec.at(i) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

ouput:

```
Enter name/path of the txt file: file.txt
The file contains:
58
63
70
56
```

of course, using `std::stoi` works only if there are no characters *after* the integer. Well, this is just an idea and of course highly modifiable.

Comment: Very nice. Just not sure why the regex object is *in* the loop, though - it's possible it might be more efficient to place it before, and construct it once.

Comment: Ah true. my bad. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the logic is wrong, as you noticed.
You remove characters from the beginning if the current character is not a digit nor a `)`.

What you probably want to do is remove the comments, so why not search for the start `(*` and end `*)` and remove everything in between?

```
std::vector<std::string> fileContent;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    //Find starting character sequence
    auto begin = line.find("(*");
    if (begin != std::string::npos)
    {
        //Find matching ending sequence, it's not a comment otherwise
        auto end = line.find("*)", begin);
        if (end != std::string::npos)
            line.erase(line.begin() + begin, line.begin() + end + 2);
    }

    fileContent.push_back(line);
}
```

Comment: I understand the code and see where I went wrong but the issue is the fstream and the infile isn't compatible with the class string.

Comment: @user5468794 What do you mean? Besides, the code didn't go through a compiler, I'll check it as soon as I have access to my computer

Comment: @user5468794 What do you mean not compatible? Add "std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");" before the while loop.

Comment: The way I'm getting the file through the fstream and istream_iterator, the getline is having issues with the line, infile you posted above. And no worries.

Comment: Before adding the line to the fileContent do a check to see if the string is empty "  if(line.find_first_not_of(' ') != std::string::npos) {... push_back...}"

Comment: @user5468794 Found the error: I switched the parameters of `std::getline` around :)

Comment: Ok I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. One time it removed all the numbers and the other time it had everything for the output.

Comment: @user5468794 You should debug in this case

Answer (score 0):

You could use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read past the closing `')'` character then you know the next read will be your number:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(ifs, line)) // line by line
    {
        std::string skip;
        int value;

        // skip data upto and past ')', then read number
        if(std::getline(std::istringstream(line), skip, ')') >> value)
            std::cout << "found: " << value << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
found: 58
found: 63
found: 70
found: 56
```