# Removing section between parenthesis on every line if present

Tags: c++, find, stdstring, erase

I have a file that I am inputting that has a bunch of lines that look like `(* blah blah 4324 blah*) 23`. I'm trying to remove everything between the parenthesis and keep the number that's just after the closed parenthesis.

```
ifstream infile{"nums.txt"};
istream_iterator<string> infile_begin_iter {infile};
istream_iterator<string> eof;
vector<string> cleanNums {infile_begin_iter, eof};

for(int i=0; i<cleanNums.size(); i++){
    int openParen=cleanNums[i].find("(*");
    int closeParen=cleanNums[i].find("*)");
    int distance=openParen-closeParen;
    cleanNums[i].erase(closeParen, distance);
}
```

That code keeps causing my program to crash. I have been looking around here for different things like getline but there I find it only shows me everything before the deliminator.

Comment: How does it cause your program to crash? Do you get an error message? How is `cleanNums` defined? We need a bit more information to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Use debugger to resolve your crash. :)
and Post Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What if there is a line without parentheses? What do you think [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) will return then? What do you think happens when you call [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) with those values?

Comment: Typically, the second parameter to erase() is not the last index/iterator to erase, but a ***count*** of how many elements to erase.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373898/remove-comments-from-file-and-keep-integers/39374232

Comment: we're missing a definition of `cleanNums`, but if it is a `std::vector`, `erase` actually expects 2 iterators and its behavior is well-defined for out-of-bounds iterators (will do nothing if there are no brackets found)

Comment: Use `std::getline` to read up to the closing `)` then you know the next thing you read is your number.

Comment: I take that back, `cleanNums` has a member `find` method and therefore is not a vector. Also `cleanNums.find` returns `int` so its probably a string. @SamVarshavchik has it right then, it's an overload that takes offset and count: `cleanNums[i].erase(openParen,closeParen+1-openParen);`

Comment: edit: updated original post with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no declaration given, I assume that `cleanNums` is a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Now to the code snippet from the question: `std::string::find()` returns a `size_type` (i.e. usually some integer type) for the position where the given string was found. So `openParen` and `closeParen` will be the index where the opening and closing parenthesis are found - if they are found at all. [std::string::erase()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), when called with `size_type`-typed arguments interprets these arguments as starting index and length of the part that shall be erased. However, you call it as if it where the starting index and the last index of the part that shall be removed. So what you have to do is to use these both indices to calculate the length of the part that shall be removed before passing it to erase().

And there is another problem, probably the one which causes your program to crash: You do not check whether both `std::string::find()` calls actually found something. Because if the do not, then they return `std::string::npos`, which is usually larger than the size of most strings. That results in the indices being out of range, and `std::string::erase()` throws a `std::out_of_range` exception. Boom, program crash!

So, what is the lesson here?
Do not *assume* what kind of parameters a function/method expects, if you are not sure about that, but **look it up in your favourite C++ reference**. It is OK if the compiler does not read the documentation of a function it uses/compiles, but the programmer should read the documentation of a function he/she uses at least once.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read past the closing `')'` character then you know the next read will be your number:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");

    std::string skip; // read in parts you want to skip
    int value;        // the value you want to keep

    // skip data upto and past ')', then read number
    while(std::getline(ifs, skip, ')') >> value)
        std::cout << "found: " << value << '\n'; // output just the number
}
```